# Side by side plots with phplot

Tags: php, graph, phplot

I'm using phplot. I need to show each graph under another. I try to do this using `$plot->SetPlotAreaPixels()` method but it's work not correctly.

```
$data = array(
   // plots data 
);

$w = 1600; // width
$h = 280; // one graph height


$plot = new PHPlot($w, $h * count($data));
$plot->SetPrintImage(0);
// ... more settings ...

$i = 0;
foreach (array_keys($data) as $title) {
    $plot->SetPlotAreaPixels(null, $h * $i, null, $h);
    $plot->SetDataValues($data[$title]);
    $plot->DrawGraph();

    $i++;
}


$plot->PrintImage();
```

But this looks strange:

[image]

What's wrong in my code?

http://pastebin.com/wejv5cpD

Answer (score 0):

I`m replace `$plot->SetPlotAreaPixels(null, $h * $i, null, $h);` to `$plot->SetNewPlotAreaPixels($margin_left, $h * $i + $margin_top, $w - $margin_right, $h * ($i + 1) - $margin_bottom);` and set up margins. Now it works fine.